# Why are parameter names necessary in an interface definition? I am allowed to choose new parameter names during implementation

Tags: c#

Not sure if this is a silly question, but I just noticed this:

```
public interface IActivityDao : IDao<Activity>
{
    IList<Activity> GetAllSinceSequence(long sequence, int count);
}

public class ActivityDao : AbstractNHibernateDao<Core.Domain.Activity>, IActivityDao
{        
    public IList<Activity> GetAllSinceSequence(long sequence, int maxRecords)
    {

    }
}
```

Inside of my implementation I have called my second parameter 'maxRecords.' Yet, in the interface, it is defined as 'count.' The compiler still consider the interface implemented, which is good, but can lead to a bit of ambiguity. Clearly, I should rename one of the parameters to match the other.

I played around a bit before making the rename and noticed something interesting. I'm not allowed to declare my interface as:

```
public interface IActivityDao : IDao<Activity>
{
    IList<Activity> GetAllSinceSequence(long, int);
}
```

Is this just the compiler being overly protective against C# symantics? What purpose do the parameter names in an interface's method serve other than to make the code more readable? It seems to me that it invites ambiguity if the parameter names aren't forced upon implementations.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Parameter names are required in an interface declaration for clarity of implementation and for reference.  If someone were using your interface, the names of the method parameters are meant to be self documenting so the consumer of the interface understands what to pass to the method (eg when viewing the method description via IntelliSense)

And yes, when you implement the interface you can name the parameters whatever you want.

Comment: You deserve more upvotes. You have the best answer by far. You answered the OP's question quite succinctly.

Comment: Well, sort of. The answer, while clear, doesn't really address the last sentence of my post. Why is there no guarantee that the parameters will be named the same during implementation? If the only intention is to self-document and be clear -- why not bring that clarity all the way down to implementations? I don't want to accidentally advertise my method as accepting 'count' when I really expect 'maxResults.'

Comment: Because you might want more specific self-documentation at the implementation level. Say you created an IBinaryMathOperation interface, with a method Execute(int operand1, int operand2). You then implemented an AddOperation class implementing the interface. The "operands" to an add method are more specifically known as "addends", and you may want to call them that in the specific implementation of Execute().

Comment: One more reason; say you implemented three classes, then noticed they all had methods with the same name and similar purpose and decided to "extract" an interface. Which is the easier refactor; defining the interface with the method and declaring each class as implementing it, changing the function name as necessary, or defining the interface, defining the classes as implementing it, changing the method name AND all the parameters?

Comment: @KeithS, I vote for option 3) -- use ReSharper and click "Extract Interface" ;)

Comment: That pulls the parameter names from one class; then you apply the interface to the rest of the classes (but you don't have to match parameter names).

Answer (score 11):

History.  This goes back to the very early days of .NET, back when COM ruled the world.  Being able to interop with COM was *very* important back then, nobody ever throws away everything to adopt an entirely new style of programming.

Which made COM interop strongly supported in .NET in general.  As well as the need to have named arguments for interface methods, type libraries require them.

The interesting corner case is forever the C++/CLI language.  It adopted many C++ syntax rules, including the ability to omit parameter names in declarations.  In other words, this is legal:

```
    public interface class IFoo
    {
        void bar(int, long, double);
    };
```

The type library exporter generates this declaration:

```
    HRESULT bar(
                    [in] long p1, 
                    [in] long p2, 
                    [in] double p3);
```

Very similar outcome if you implement the interface in a C# class, as autogenerated by IntelliSense:

```
class FooImpl : cpptemp36.IFoo {
    public void foo(int __p1, int __p2, double __p3) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This makes nobody happy.

Comment: I just want to say how much I have appreciated and enjoyed this answer (notably the insightful final sentence) eleven years later in 2023.

Answer (score 3):

In the new world of code quality, the parameters name at the implementation level must be the same as interface level.

In sonarqube has a rule like *'parameter names should match base declaration and other partial definitions'* and calls this *'Noncompliant Code'*:

```
interface IFoo
{
  void Bar(int i);
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
  void Bar(int z) // Noncompliant, parameter name should be i
  {
  }
}
```

The funny thing is it refers to this document which does not covering `interface`:
https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/DCL40-C.+Do+not+create+incompatible+declarations+of+the+same+function+or+object

I personally like to have code like this:

```cs
public interface IExtractor<TInput, TOutput>{
    TOutput Extract(TInput input);
}

public class CustomerExtractor : IExtractor<Order, Customer>
{
    public Customer Extract(Order order)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But the tool forces me to use the following declaring it as a **critical** issue:

```cs
    public Customer Extract(Order input)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

`input` doesn't have the same meaning as `order` in this case.

To get rid of the noise,

- If no DI involved, Use static utility classes for this sort of classes (Map, Extract, Combine, ...)
- If DI involved, trick the tool by adding a helper variable

```cs
    public Customer Extract(Order input)
    {
       var order = input;

       // use order from here on
    }
```

Comment: Have just had Sonar flag this up myself, not sure I agree with it being seen as Critical (more Info I would have said) basically for the same reason as you have said; it enables me to give the variable more meaning in the implementation (especially in the case of an interface with generics). Although i guess the answer is to put a code comment to give the extra clarity and keep the variable names the same.

Comment: Having now done the above I'm still of the opinion that having the name of the parameter the same when a general term is used (and appropriate) in the interface makes the code less clear in the class.

Answer (score 2):

Let me ask you this, is there anywhere else in the .net framework that allows you to define a method signature without parameter names?

At the end of the day all things are possible but most things are there for a reason, in this case I would imagine that this is a limit of the framework and compiler design, and does it really matter?

You are after all defining a contract for use, one would expect them to be there really.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine this is due to the *named parameters* feature in C#.  Ie, you need to be able to specify parameters by name, not just in the default order:

```
IActivityDao dao;
dao.GetAllSinceSequence(count: 1, sequence: 2);
```

Of course, the parameter names would be different if the object is cast as your instance.

```
var concreteDao = (ActivityDao) dao;
concreteDao.GetAllSinceSequence(maxRecords: 1, sequence: 2);
```

Comment: Except that said feature post-dates interfaces by most of a decade.

Answer (score 1):

Many languages like C# and VB support [named and option arguments to methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). Without the argument names in the interface, using named and optional arguments would not be possible. Naming the arguments also helps the reader understand the interface's intention and function.