# Validating function signature - interface vs type alias

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
function (n: number) {
    return {s: n};
}
```

I need to create a validator for the signature. From what I've read I have two options:

**Interface**

```
interface ValidatorFnInterface {
    (n: number): {
        [key: string]: any;
    };
}
```

**Type alias**

```
type ValidatorFnType = (n: number) => {
    [key: string]: any
};
```

And they can be used like this:

```
let f1: ValidatorFnInterface = function (n: number) {
    return {s: n};
};

let f2: ValidatorFnType = function (n: number) {
    return {s: n};
};
```

Typescript `lib.d.ts` seems to be using type aliases, while angular2 code seems to be using interface. My question is when to use what? Is there any logic I should use when deciding or is it a matter of preference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: Interfaces vs Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233735/typescript-interfaces-vs-types)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently classes in TypeScript can only implement `interfaces` not arbitrary types. So in general, if you want other classes to be able to use your types as something to implement, you should use interfaces. Likewise interfaces can only `extend` other interfaces.

On the negative side for interfaces, they can not express intersection or union types, so if you want that in one single type you're stuck with type aliases.

Comment: thanks, so what you're saying you would stick to interfaces for functions signature validation?

Comment: @Maximus That depends on your requirements. I personally like to express my types with type aliases because it feels cleaner. But interfaces are probably a safer bet, and more reusable.

Comment: thanks. Did type alias appear later in the language than interfaces? Maybe that's the reason why angular2 uses interfaces. Also, what can you say about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137350/defining-typescript-callback-type#comment47535906_14249517) comment?