# How to have anonymous object with function property matching another function's signature?

Tags: typescript

Consider this:

```
function doIt(thing: SomeThing, iterations: number): void {
  // ...
}

class ThingProcessor{
  private state: {
    // how to avoid specifying the arguments again?
    action: (thing: SomeThing, iterations: number) => void
  };
}
```

In this example, I have to specify the `doIt` function parameters twice. I'd rather indicate that `state.action` is `typeof(doIt)`, e.g. use the same signature as the `doIt` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reuse function signature definition in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241357/how-to-reuse-function-signature-definition-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `typeof` operator on the function to get it's type

```
function doIt(thing: SomeThing, iterations: number): void {
    // ...
}

class ThingProcessor {
    private state: {
        // how to avoid specifying the arguments again?
        action: typeof doIt;
    };
}
```

Comment: Wow, I was so close! Thanks!