# Pass Callback function to child as props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is how my child container declares Ownprops

```
export interface OwnProps {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: "callback function"
}
```

I will pass a callback function from parent to this child so that i can trigger the parent function from child.

I am not able to declare it in OwnProps.

I tried this

```
prop2: React.PropTypes.func
```

It gave error "React has no exported member PropTypes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to use [callback types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types)?

If your callback is of type `() => void`:

```
interface OwnProps {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: () => void;
}
```

- [See similar answer on classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137350/defining-typescript-callback-type).