# How to define type for a function callback (as any function type, not universal any) used in a method parameter

Tags: typescript

Currently I have type definition as:

```
interface Param {
    title: string;
    callback: any;
}
```

I need something like:

```
interface Param {
    title: string;
    callback: function;
}
```

but the 2nd one is not being accepted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are strongly-typed functions as parameters possible in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638990/are-strongly-typed-functions-as-parameters-possible-in-typescript)

Comment: it's upper case `callback:Function` instead of `lower case callback:function`

Comment: I found out `Function` wasn't compatible is one case so I created an "AnyFunction" type:
`export type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;`

Answer (score 673):

The global type `Function` serves this purpose.

Additionally, if you intend to invoke this callback with 0 arguments and will ignore its return value, the type `() => void` matches all functions taking no arguments.

Comment: this thing is missing in [basic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Comment: It's not a basic type because you should define your arguments and return values. something like callback: (number: number) => void; is much more useful for type checking than callback: function; would be.

Comment: @kpup To be clear, are you saying *not* to use capital F `Function` as shown in the first line of this answer, and saying the second paragraph (using type of `() => void` or whatever matches the use case) is preferred?

Comment: FWIW, docs on function types are available [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types)

Comment: @jeff-bowman Fair enough. In hindsight, I completely agree that my edit should be its own answer. However, and no offense to Ryan, but Ryan's position has no relevance to whether an improvement to an answer he's previously posted should be updated. If we weren't allowed to edit out-of-date answers due to people's positions, then stackoverflow would be a much less useful place. Also, [_Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). This answer **needs** updating. One way or another.

Comment: `() => void` matches **all** functions taking no arguments is also 100% incorrect.

Comment: @SgtPooki post your own answer. That's how the site works.

Comment: @SgtPooki Ryan's correct: Edits can be substantial, but should _preserve the meaning of the answer_. If it were appropriate for anyone to change a top-rated answer freely to whatever they deem is right, SO would lose any value in its ranking/voting of those answers. If you think an answer's core meaning needs updating, leave a comment and/or write a new answer. And to your point about author's positions: These rules about respecting the original author apply to everyone, but _highly-visible and highly-voted answers from authoritative sources_ are particularly good places to exercise that rule.

Comment: Note that [ESLint gives some advice _against_ using `Function`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.33.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md) as a type directly -- quote "Don't use `Function` as a type. The `Function` type accepts any function-like value. It provides no type safety when calling the function, which can be a common source of bugs. It also accepts things like class declarations, which will throw at runtime as they will not be called with `new`."

Comment: @SgtPooki I like the conciseness of this answer, but I like your edits as well. If you post them as an answer, I'll upvote them.

Comment: I believe @Toastrackenigma's comment shows that this answer has not aged well. We need a new answer.

Answer (score 347):

Typescript from v1.4 has the `type` keyword which declares a type alias (analogous to a `typedef` in C/C++). You can declare your callback type thus:

```
type CallbackFunction = () => void;
```

which declares a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing. A function that takes zero or more arguments of any type and returns nothing would be:

```
type CallbackFunctionVariadic = (...args: any[]) => void;
```

Then you can say, for example,

```
let callback: CallbackFunctionVariadic = function(...args: any[]) {
  // do some stuff
};
```

If you want a function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments and returns anything (including void):

```
type CallbackFunctionVariadicAnyReturn = (...args: any[]) => any;
```

You can specify some mandatory arguments and then a set of additional arguments (say a string, a number and then a set of extra args) thus:

```
type CallbackFunctionSomeVariadic =
  (arg1: string, arg2: number, ...args: any[]) => void;
```

This can be useful for things like EventEmitter handlers.

Functions can be typed as strongly as you like in this fashion, although you can get carried away and run into combinatoric problems if you try to nail everything down with a type alias.

Comment: Between `Function` and `(...args: any[]) => any` what is preferred?

Comment: @ahong: Personally I would prefer the latter as it provides a signature... normally. `...args: any[]` isn't very useful.

Comment: `type CallbackFunctionSomeVariadic =
  (arg1: string, arg2: number, ...args: any[]) => void;`
what i was looking for, ty.

Comment: Seems I was able to export and reuse a definition in other components like this `export type CallbackFunctionSomething = (page: number, sort: blablabla) => void`

Comment: I found out an interesting thing: **`Function` is NOT the same as `(...args: any[]) => any`**

Answer (score 89):

Following from Ryan's answer, I think that the interface you are looking for is defined as follows:

```
interface Param {
    title: string;
    callback: () => void;
}
```

Answer (score 74):

You can define a function type in interface in various ways,

1. general way:

```js
export interface IParam {
  title: string;
  callback(arg1: number, arg2: number): number;
}
```

2. If you would like to use property syntax then,

```js
export interface IParam {
  title: string;
  callback: (arg1: number, arg2: number) => number;
}
```

3. If you declare the function type first then,

```js
type MyFnType = (arg1: number, arg2: number) => number;

export interface IParam {
  title: string;
  callback: MyFnType;
}
```

Using is very straight forward,

```
function callingFn(paramInfo: IParam):number {
    let needToCall = true;
    let result = 0;
   if(needToCall){
     result = paramInfo.callback(1,2);
    }

    return result;
}
```

4. You can  declare a function type literal also , which mean a function can accept another function as it's parameter. parameterize function can be called as callback also.

```js
export interface IParam{
  title: string;
  callback(lateCallFn?:
             (arg1:number,arg2:number)=>number):number;

}
```

Comment: this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 40):

Here's an example of a function that accepts a callback

```
const sqk = (x: number, callback: ((_: number) => number)): number => {
  // callback will receive a number and expected to return a number
  return callback (x * x);
}

// here our callback will receive a number
sqk(5, function(x) {
  console.log(x); // 25
  return x;       // we must return a number here
});
```

If you don't care about the return values of callbacks (most people don't know how to utilize them in any effective way), you can use `void`

```
const sqk = (x: number, callback: ((_: number) => void)): void => {
  // callback will receive a number, we don't care what it returns
  callback (x * x);
}

// here our callback will receive a number
sqk(5, function(x) {
  console.log(x); // 25
  // void
});
```

Note, the signature I used for the `callback` parameter ...

```
const sqk = (x: number, callback: ((_: number) => number)): number
```

I would say this is a TypeScript deficiency because we are expected to provide a *name* for the callback parameters. In this case I used `_` because it's not usable inside the `sqk` function.

However, if you do this

```
// danger!! don't do this
const sqk = (x: number, callback: ((number) => number)): number
```

It's *valid* TypeScript, but it will interpreted as ...

```
// watch out! typescript will think it means ...
const sqk = (x: number, callback: ((number: any) => number)): number
```

Ie, TypeScript will think the parameter *name* is `number` and the implied type is `any`. This is obviously not what we intended, but alas, that is how TypeScript works.

So don't forget to provide the parameter names when typing your function parameters... stupid as it might seem.

Answer (score 39):

There are various ways to define function types; however, some are better than others.

Although it is possible to use [**`Function`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), the JavaScript function object, **don't do that**.

Source: [TypeScript ESLint plugin](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) recommended rule [ban-types](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.32.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md#default-options)

> - Avoid the Function type, as it provides little safety for the following reasons:
>
>   - It provides no type safety when calling the value, which means it's easy to provide the wrong arguments.
>   - It accepts class declarations, which will fail when called, as they are called without the new keyword.

TypeScript supports multiple other ways. For example, [**function type expressions**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions). This method highly resembles [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

**If arguments and return values are known to be of a certain form, then they should be typed.** This *should* be the case for a callback.

For example,

```js
interface Param {
  callback: (foo: string, bar: number) => void
}
```

Note that these types can be as complex as needed, for example using [object types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) or [types created from other types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-types.html).

**If the types are truly unknown** then prefer [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) over `any`.

Source: TypeScript ESLint plugin recommended rule [no-explicit-any](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.32.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md)

> When `any` is used, all compiler type checks around that value are ignored.

From the TS docs,

> `unknown` is the type-safe counterpart of `any`.

**Thus**, using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax),

```js
interface Param {
  callback: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown
}
```

Comment: This is the most concise answer and should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 29):

There are four abstract function types, you can use them separately when you know your function will take an argument(s) or not, will return a data or not.

```
export declare type fEmptyVoid = () => void;
export declare type fEmptyReturn = () => any;
export declare type fArgVoid = (...args: any[]) => void;
export declare type fArgReturn = (...args: any[]) => any;
```

like this:

```
public isValid: fEmptyReturn = (): boolean => true;
public setStatus: fArgVoid = (status: boolean): void => this.status = status;
```

For use only one type as any function type we can combine all abstract types together, like this:

```
export declare type fFunction = fEmptyVoid | fEmptyReturn | fArgVoid | fArgReturn;
```

then use it like:

```
public isValid: fFunction = (): boolean => true;
public setStatus: fFunction = (status: boolean): void => this.status = status;
```

In the example above everything is correct. But the usage example in bellow is not correct from the point of view of most code editors.

```
// you can call this function with any type of function as argument
public callArgument(callback: fFunction) {

    // but you will get editor error if call callback argument like this
    callback();
}
```

Correct call for editors is like this:

```
public callArgument(callback: fFunction) {

    // pay attention in this part, for fix editor(s) error
    (callback as fFunction)();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Hopefully, this will help...

```
interface Param {
    title: string;
    callback: (error: Error, data: string) => void;
}
```

Or in a Function

```
let myfunction = (title: string, callback: (error: Error, data: string) => void): string => {

    callback(new Error(`Error Message Here.`), "This is callback data.");
    return title;

}
```

Answer (score 8):

> Typescript: How to define type for a function callback used in a *method* parameter?

You can declare the callback as 1) *function property* or 2) *method*:

```
interface ParamFnProp {
    callback: (a: Animal) => void; // function property
}

interface ParamMethod {
    callback(a: Animal): void; // method
}
```

There is an important *typing* difference since [TS 2.6](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types):

You get stronger ("sound") types in `--strict` or `--strictFunctionTypes` mode, when a *function property* is declared. Let's take an example:

```
const animalCallback = (a: Animal): void => { } // Animal is the base type for Dog
const dogCallback = (d: Dog): void => { }
```

```
// function property variant
const param11: ParamFnProp = { callback: dogCallback } // error: not assignable
const param12: ParamFnProp = { callback: animalCallback } // works

// method variant
const param2: ParamMethod = { callback: dogCallback } // now it works again ...
```

Technically spoken, methods are *bivariant* and function properties [*contravariant*](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) in their arguments under `strictFunctionTypes`. Methods are still [checked more permissively](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant) (even if not sound) to be a bit more practical in combination with built-in types like `Array`.

#### Summary

- There is a type difference between function property and method declaration
- Choose a function property for stronger types, if possible

[Playground sample code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.3&ssl=30&ssc=80&pln=25&pc=1#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)

Answer (score 4):

In typescript 4.8, `Function` type gives error. Instead we can write the type explicitly as `fn: () => void`.

If you want to use `args` as well,

`function debounce(fn: (...args: any[]) => void, ms = 300) {`

Answer (score 2):

I've just started using Typescript and I've been trying to solve a similar problem like this; how to tell the Typescript that I'm passing a callback without an `interface`.

After browsing a few answers on Stack Overflow and GitHub issues, I finally found a solution that may help anyone with the same problem.

A function's type can be defined with `(arg0: type0) => returnType` and we can use this type definition in another function's parameter list.

```js
function runCallback(callback: (sum: number) => void, a: number, b: number): void {
    callback(a + b);
}

// Another way of writing the function would be:
// let logSum: (sum: number) => void = function(sum: number): void {
//     console.log(sum);
// };
function logSum(sum: number): void {
    console.log(`The sum is ${sum}.`);
}

runCallback(logSum, 2, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for input callback function like on change event then use the following

```
type Props = {
  callBack:  ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `...args: unknown[]`, we can use 1 object argument with generic type:

```
interface Param<D> {
    title: string;
    callback: (args: D) => void;
}
```

where `D` can be something like `{name: string, email: string}`