# How to specify function parameters for React component callback with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component in TypeScript that looks something like this:

```
interface FooDetails {
    name: string
    latitude: number,
    longitude: number,
}

interface FooSelectorProps {
    onDetailsChanged: Function,
}

class FooSelector extends React.Component<FooSelectorProps, any> {
    constructor(props: FooSelectorProps, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    onTravelTypeChange(event) {
        this.setState({ travelType: event.target.value });
    }

    onDetailsChange(fooData) {
        this.props.onDetailsChanged({
            name: fooData.name,
            latitude: fooData.latitude,
            longitude: fooData.longitude,
        });
    }

    render() {
            return <div>...Foo selection UI...</div>
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to specify that the `onDetailsChanged` function in my propTypes (`FooSelectorProps`) takes a  `FooDetails` object, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: not sure, but check this link, may be helpful: [**LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689966/typescript-how-to-define-type-for-a-function-callback-as-any-function-type-no)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: How to define type for a function callback (as any function type, not universal any) used in a method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689966/typescript-how-to-define-type-for-a-function-callback-as-any-function-type-no)

Answer (score 34):

Instead of using the global type `Function` for type of `onDetailsChanged`, you can write out the type instead, so change `FooSelectorProps` to:

```
interface FooSelectorProps {
    onDetailsChanged: ((details: FooDetails) => void)
}
```

then you'll get type checking for the `onDetailsChanged` callback.