# How to declare a function type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am working with typescript and passing a function into another function.

If I have a function that is passed into another function in typescript how should I write the type?

I have tried `successHandler: function` but this doesn't appear to work.

```
export function useSubscription(address: string, successHandler: function) {
   successHandler(address)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: How to define type for a function callback (as any function type, not universal any) used in a method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689966/typescript-how-to-define-type-for-a-function-callback-as-any-function-type-no)

Answer (score 11):

Declare a type with a function signature and pass it around as the type:

```
type SuccessHandler = (address: string) => string;

function useSubscription(address: string, successHandler: SuccessHandler) {
    successHandler(address)
}
```

Comment: `(address: string) => void` is probably better. Since `useSubscription` doesn't use the return value from `successHandler`, it shouldn't require one.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare it like this:

```
export function useSubscription(address: string, successHandler: (string) => void)) {
   successHandler(address)
}
```

The change is with the capital F for `Function`.

Comment: True, but this is not type checking. This is just making typescript be quiet. Since we call `successHandler(address)`, we should declare a type that insures that will work, ie `(address: string) => void`.

Comment: Of course it is type checking. You can't pass anything that is not a function. In the original question there is no definition for the function. While it's reasonable to assume `(address: string) => void`, `(address: string) => ANYTHING` is also valid.

Comment: What I mean is the type checking's not doing it's job; it shuts typescript up without providing the protection typescript is meant to provide. We want to know we can pass `address` to `successHandler`. `Function` doesn't insure that. As for your second point, yes, `(address: string) => void` permits `(address: string) => ANYTHING`. The `void` keyword tells typescript it can ignore the return value.

Comment: But we do check the address type as well, you are just double specifying that address has to be a string

Answer (score 0):

Her you can use callback function as a strongly typed parameter like this

```js
class Menu {
    addItem(callback: (n: string) => any) : void {
        callback('Egg Roles');
    }
}
var menu = new Menu();

var itemCallBack = (result: string) : void => {
    alert(result);
}

menu.addItem(itemCallBack);
```

Here is the working example. Let me know if u have any doubt.