# React prop types with TypeScript - how to have a function type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is there a best practice for having a function type with React prop types with TypeScript?

I assumed this would work but in fact it errored:

```
type Props = {
  onClick: Function
};

const Submit = ({ onClick }: Props) => {
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
      click me
    </button>
  );
```

Following this thread I got it working, but it seems needlessly verbose: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20007

```
type Props = {
  onClick: (...args: any[]) => any;
};

const Submit = ({ onClick }: Props) => {
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
      click me
    </button>
  );
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

### Concerning `Function` and best practices

[`Function`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9ff24b6/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L272-L304) in practice has unsufficient type-safety, being the super-type of all functions. You better replace it with  a [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types) - see the "Solutions" section down under.

In above example, `Function` is not assignable to the more narrow `onClick` function type, which causes the error at hand ([Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChSYBPMJOABRzAGc4BeOAb1LjggDsAwgBtgaANYAuOADEArnwzB+pAL4Bucmn5N4AZVkAjEMHjsAFB16CR4uCqkMIzAJRsAfNzhnPPADwHZGBh+OCoaVnwAoP58K2FRMVYOfnjxFTc4AHpMuAB3YAATWgByOQUYJT5i0OpaPgh4FCYmYABzPhQDIVpguDQbMTgACxQ+Au6oHx4+gbgQJCnfTKjgvg8eZ3JsuE6IADdaYBYmFHm4JCgcKB2WGCHaTAghIQh8vlaJUi0+HTnKVLEAAlRuMLlIyooQuYkHspMh0DAAHQAWQgsiYSAAogc+DBXKwMhxvkwnkhES9WmZ8P0EkgCgBCfDOFRfbRYPhSMxmGFIXFw4hI1HorE4mC+QEAFWRABkAEKBVaY7rzXEAGjgQox2N5MDc+IyewghXxfwBwLGEyyOQuVyAA)).

In addition to [mentioned issue,](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20007#issuecomment-405766256) here is what [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function) say about `Function`:

> This is an untyped function call and is generally best avoided because of the unsafe any return type. If need to accept an arbitrary function but don’t intend to call it, the type `() => void` is generally safer.

[typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) has *discarded* `Function` with the [`ban-types`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.4.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md) rule, [emitting following message](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/1cb8ca4/packages/eslint-plugin/src/rules/ban-types.ts#L74-L81) with default configuration (see also [here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.4.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md#default-options)):

> The `Function` type accepts any function-like value. It provides no type safety when calling the function, which can be a common source of bugs.
> If you are expecting the function to accept certain arguments, you should explicitly define the function shape.

### Better solutions

React already comes with [built-in event handler-types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/927f70d/types/react/index.d.ts#L1303-L1316) to handle [common events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events).

For example `click` ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChSYBPMJOABRzAGc4BeOAb1LjggDsAwgBtgaANYAuRMRgA6ALIQArkyQBRAG5I+MABIo+AEyFIoAHl0AVeQBkAQkpgx+akyG0wAfKQC+AbnI0fiZ4AGUlACMQYHh2AAoOXkERcTgfKQYIZgBKNm8eOO4eODMIx2c+OCoaVnwyp358JOFRMVYOfhbxH3zinjQUsTh3Ip4zAHp6it7soA)):

```
type Props = {
  onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>
};

const Submit = ({ onClick }: Props) => <button onClick={onClick}> click </button>
```

A more general alternative is to use [function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types) as follows:

```
type Props = { 
  onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void
};
```

`void` is more restrictive than `any`. There is no chance to return a value in the callback by accident, which would be possible with `any`.

In summary, we embrace typing capabilities of TypeScript instead of using `Function` or `any`.
The parameter now is known to be `MouseEvent` and the return type `void`, identifying it as a callback.

### Related

[Typescript: How to define type for a function callback (as any function type, not universal any) used in a method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689966/typescript-how-to-define-type-for-a-function-callback-as-any-function-type-no)

Answer (score 10):

You can simply write it like this, which prevents any and is more telling. Especially for custom functions:

Interface Props {
     onClick: (e: Event) => void;
}

This will tell the calling component, what onClick will expect and what the parameters are.

Hope this helps. Happy coding.