# Typescript error - don't use function as a type

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have started to use `TypeScript` in my `React-Native` project

My linter doesn't like function as a type, how can I refactor my hoc to pass my linter?

AppNavigator:

```
const withHeader = (
    screen: Function,
    routeName: string,
    Header,
): StackNavigator =>
    createStackNavigator(
        {
            [routeName]: {
                screen,
                navigationOptions: ({routeName, props}) => ({
                    header: props => <Header {...props} />,
                }),
            },
        },
        {
            initialRoute: 'Home',
            cardStyle: {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                opacity: 1,
            },
            transitionConfig: () => ({
                containerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                },
            }),
        },
    );
```

My packager also gives me an error with the same file:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./navigation/AppNavigator` from `C:\Users\Matt\sites\IAapp\App.tsx`: The module `./navigation/AppNavigator` could not be found from `C:\Users\Matt\sites\IAapp\App.tsx`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

Comment: Type it as a more specific function `() => {}`. `Function` is `any` of functions.

Comment: I have changed that, linter still gives me the same error

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "my linter doesn't like" it?  I think for this to be a [mcve] as described in [ask], you should provide the specific error about `Function` and where it occurs, and what your linter config looks like.  Enough for someone to diagnose.  Otherwise it'll be hard to advise.  Oh, and the error at the bottom seems to be a separate question, right?

Comment: check if this answers your first question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689966/typescript-how-to-define-type-for-a-function-callback-as-any-function-type-no