# Pass in function and other properties to React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

Our team has a convention to pass properties to Functional Components this way:

```
type FCProps = {
  aVar: SomeType,
  anotherVar: string
}

const MyFC: React.FC<FCProps> = ({aVar, anotherVar}) => {
    return <SomeComponent aVar={aVar} anotherVar={anotherVar} />
}
```

After looking through some [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) and React [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) related to Functional Components, the best I could come up with was:

```
type FCProps = {
  aVar: SomeType,
  anotherVar: string,
  (myBool: boolean): void
}

const MyFC: React.FC<FCProps> = (props: FCProps) => {
    const someValue = props(1)
    return <SomeComponent aVar={props.aVar} anotherVar={props.anotherVar} handlerFunc={props} />
}
```

What I really would like is something that looks like:

```
type FCProps = {
  aVar: SomeType,
  anotherVar: string,
  (myBool: boolean): void
}

const MyFC: React.FC<FCProps> = ({aVar, anotherVar, myFunc}) => {
    const someValue = props(1)
    return <SomeComponent aVar={aVar} anotherVar={anotherVar} handlerFunc={myFunc} />
}
```

Is something like that (or close to it) possible?

Comment: Just add a property to the `FCProps` for your function. `myFunc: (myBool: boolean) => void` and call it `prop.myFunc(true)` (or using destructuring `myFunc(true)`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define type for a function callback (as any function type, not universal any) used in a method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689966/how-to-define-type-for-a-function-callback-as-any-function-type-not-universal)

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thank you for the quick response! If you make an answer out of your first comment, I'll mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: I believe there's no need for another answer as the information is already available in the [_duplicate candidate_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29689966/1218980). If you have the option to accept it, it'll help reduce the noise on Stack Overflow! :)