# How to dynamically import moment.js in a react app (with typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, code-splitting

I'm trying to do some code splitting and moment.js is one of the targeted packages I want to isolate in a separate chunk. I'm doing it like this:

```
const myFn = async (currentNb) => {
   const moment = (await import('moment')).default()          
   const dateUnix: number = moment(currentNb).valueOf()
   [...]
}
```

But I get the following error: `this expression is not callable. Type Moment has no call signatures` . So I guess I should be doing something like `moment.valueOf(currentNb)` but I'm not really sure. Can someone put some light to this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure as to what's the proper type for `moment`, but it looks like it's a `Function`.. Worth trying.. Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689966/how-to-define-type-for-a-function-callback-as-any-function-type-not-universal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently my syntax was incorrect. I finally found how to solve this problem. I need to import it as follows:

```
const {default: moment} = await import('moment')
```

I found the answer in the webpack documentation:

> The reason we need default is that since webpack 4, when importing a
> CommonJS module, the import will no longer resolve to the value of
> module.exports, it will instead create an artificial namespace object
> for the CommonJS module.