# Typescript generic Rest operator with corresponding callback

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

i have recently picked up Typescript because it seemed interesting. I have used generics in C# before and managed to do quiet a few things with generics in Typescript but now im stumped for the following use case:

I have a generic function that takes in any number of Rest arguments. These arguments are than passed to a callback function which is also provided. But i cannot seem to figure out how to make the typescript compiler accept the types i provide to implicitly be passed into the callback function.

```
async SampleFunction(
    cb: () => void,
    ...args: any[]
)
```

with this as sample usage:

```
let stringVariable = "lorem";
let numberVariable = 8;

SampleFunction(
    (stringArg, numberArg) => {},
    stringVariable,
    numberVariable,
)
```

This example results in arguments that think they are implicitly type 'any'.

my question hereby is: how can i make this function definition so that i could pass in any aditional arguments which then get their type passed into the callback function as they are passed in the same order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Etheryte i got onto the right search track.

I found the sollution i wanted which is:

```
function SampleFunction<T extends any[]>(
    cb: (...args: T) => void,
    ...args: T
): void {}

let stringVariable = 'lorem';
let numberVariable = 8;

SampleFunction(
    (a, b) => {}, 
    stringVariable, 
    numberVariable
);
```

This implicitly passes the right argument types from the function into the callback

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype). The `(...args: any[]) => any` type in the extends allows [any function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37195144/1470607) to be passed as the callback regardless of its signature, and infers the rest from the passed function.

```
function sampleFunction<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  callback: T,
  ...args: Parameters<T>
) {}

sampleFunction((a: string, b: number) => null, "foo"); // Doesn't pass
sampleFunction((a: string, b: number) => null, "foo", "bar"); // Doesn't pass
sampleFunction((a: string, b: number) => null, "foo", 42); // Passes
sampleFunction((a: string, b: number) => null, 42, "bar"); // Doesn't pass
```

Comment: This answer helps a lot but i only have a slight problem with it. A missmatch in argument length is getting properly reported but the implicit argument types is still any. i would love to have them be the type of the arguments implicitly.