# Angular: pass a method as parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have these two methods which are almost similar:

```
private firstFunction () {
    this.serviceOne.methodOne().subscribe(
      res => {
        return  resultOne = res;
      },
      err => {}
    );
  }

private secondFunction () {
    this.serviceTwo.methodTwo().subscribe(
      res => {
        return  resultTwo = res;
      },
      err => {}
    );
  }
```

I want to write a generic function, like this:

```
genericFunction (service ,method , result  ) {
        service.method().subscribe(
          res => {
            return  result = res;
          },
          err => {}
        );
      }
```

And consequently I want to get something like this working:

```
genericFunction (serviceOne , methodOne , resultOne );
genericFunction (serviceTwo , methodTwo , resultTwo );
```

Actually, I cannot find how to pass `methodOne` and `methodTwo` as params. Any sugestions?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638990/are-strongly-typed-functions-as-parameters-possible-in-typescript

Comment: Are you sure you're not falling into the trap of trying to [return a value from an async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code.

Firstly, you want to modify the field you pass in as a parameter (as suggested by `result = res`. You can't pass in a reference to a field, but you can pass in the field name, and use indexing to change the field. `keyof T` will allow you to pass in the field in a type safe way.

Secondly if you want to access a method on a service. Again we can do this passing in the method name, and we can constrain the service to have a method with the passed in method name, that returns an `Observable`. The result of the `Observable` can also be constrained to be of the same type of the field we are going to assign it to in order for the method to be fully type safe.

```
declare class Service1 {
    method1() : Observable<number>
}
declare class Service2 {
    method2() : Observable<string>
}
class MyClass {
    resultOne!: number;
    resultTwo!: string;

    constructor() {
        this.genericFunction(new Service1(), "method1", "resultOne");
        this.genericFunction(new Service2(), "method2", "resultTwo");
        this.genericFunction(new Service1(), "method1", "resultTwo"); // error resultTwo is a string, the method return Observable<number>
        this.genericFunction(new Service2(), "method", "resultTwo"); // error method does not exit on Service2
        this.genericFunction(new Service2(), "method2", "resultTwo2"); // error field does not exist on type 
    }

    genericFunction<MethodKey extends string,  ResultKey  extends keyof MyClass>(service:Record<MethodKey, ()=> Observable<MyClass[ResultKey]>>, method:MethodKey, result: ResultKey){
        service[method]().subscribe(
            res => this[result] = res,
            err => {}
        );
    }
}
```

**Note** We could have also passed in the function as a function not just as a name, but directly a typed function. The disadvantage of this is that we either have to use `bind` to ensure the service method will still have the correct `this` when it's called, or use an arrow function when calling (again to ensure the service method has the correct `this`). This is error prone though, `bind` results in an untyped function, so we can't check compatibility to the field, and someone might pass `service.method` directly and no error would be reported until runtime:

```
class MyClass {
    resultOne!: number;
    resultTwo!: string;

    constructor() {
        var service1 = new Service1()
        var service2 = new Service2()
        this.genericFunction(()=> service1.method1(), "resultOne");
        this.genericFunction(()=> service2.method2(), "resultTwo");

        this.genericFunction(service2.method2, "resultTwo"); // no error, depending on the implementation of method2 it might or might not work
        this.genericFunction(service2.method2.bind(service2), "resultOne"); // no error, the service call will work, but we store it in an incompatible variable
        this.genericFunction(()=> service1.method1(), "resultTwo");// error resultTwo is a string, the method return Observable<number>
        this.genericFunction(()=> service2.method2(), "resultTwo2");// // error field does not exist on type 
    }

    genericFunction<MethodKey extends string,  ResultKey  extends keyof MyClass>(method:()=> Observable<MyClass[ResultKey]>, result: ResultKey){
        method().subscribe(
            res => this[result] = res,
            err => {}
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try by using the following code:

```
private firstFunction () {
    let response= genericFunction(this.serviceOne.methodOne())      
}
private secondFunction () {
   let response = genericFunction(this.serviceTwo.methodTwo())    
}
```

Modify you Generic Function by just receiving a variable.

```
//if it is angular 4 or less
genericFunction (method: Observable) {
        return method.map(res => {
           return res.json();
        });
      }
 //if it is angular 5 or 6
 genericFunction (method: Observable) {
        return method.pipe(            
           map(res => {
           return res;
        }));
      }
```

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with the Angular Version. Rather it depends on whether he's using `Http` or `HttpClient`. Also in the eg above, he'll eventually have to subscribe to `response` to actually have access to the response data which beats the whole purpose of making the function generic in the first place.

Comment: @SiddAjmera take a look to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/39296015/6651984

Comment: Sorry about that. Still not able to understand the point you're trying to put here.

Comment: Why not? in response you will get the generic response provided by `genericFunction`