# How to send a function as parameter in angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rxjs

I want to send a function as a parameter. When I call it in the other function "this" and others like "HttpClient", "urlBase" are undefined.

I have searched on internet and found about bind() property, but if "this" is now defined, the others are still undefined. So I have placed all the properties that I need them in bind() function, but it looks bad to me...

This is my service function which does works perfectly.

```
 deleteEmpBusArea(employeeId: number, busAreaId: number){
   let params = {
       empId: employeeId,
       bsarId: busAreaId
   };

   return this.http.delete(`${this.envConfig.baseUrl}/employee/delete-emp-bus-area`, {params: stringify(params)}).pipe(share());
}
```

This is the function that i want to give it another function as parameter:

```
 deleteBusinessArea(area: BusinessArea){
    this.utilitiesDialogService.deleteRowFromDialog(area, this.employeeService.deleteEmpBusArea.bind(this, this.http, this.envConfig, stringify));
}
```

and also the previous called function implementation

```
 deleteRowFromDialog(element: any, funcCalled: Function){
    this.openDeleteDialog(element).afterClosed().pipe(
        switchMap((isClosed) => {
            if (isClosed === false) {
                return funcCalled(element.id);
            }
            return EMPTY;
        }),
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribed)).subscribe(() => {  
    });
}
```

Stringify is a function into a .ts file that has signature like:

```
export function stringify(json: any): any {
    ///code implementation 
}
```

I was expecting by providing "this" using bind property, the "this" will take everything that has with him ("this.http", "this.envConfig" etc) and not to write them all in .bind() . Is it that correct to provide all of them in bind?

Also, stringify being an export function I was not able to send it in bind() property and gives error:

```
A JS error occurred: Converting circular structure to JSON TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Comment: The problem you encounter is a javascript specifity, related to scope. Read this to learn more : https://javascriptplayground.com/javascript-variable-scope-this/

Comment: `bind()` is appropriate to call a function with a different environment, so this is exactly what you need here. You also have `call()` and `apply()` but those are useful when you are calling the function immediately and want to change context.

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638990/are-strongly-typed-functions-as-parameters-possible-in-typescript) has a good example. Use arrow functons to specify.

```
    defaultFunction(var: string, fun: (i: string) => number): number {
        return fun(var);
    }
```

Comment: Usaly when you need to know something which is syntactic by nature in Angular you have to search for the question in regard to typescript as this is not Angular specific.