# Angular: pass functions to service inside an object

Tags: angular

I have a component where i pass what i want to display inside a modal like this :

```
  openConfirmModal() {
    this.service.openmodal(
      {
        buttons: [ {name: 'Close'} ]
      }
    );
  }
```

The modal service is like this :

```
  openmodal(input: String) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(popupComponent, {
      data: new ModalConfirmData({
        buttons: Object.values(data)[0]
      })
    });
  }
```

Inside my popupComponent i have :

```
export class ModalPopupData {
  actions: Array<Object>;

  constructor(input?) {
    if (input) {
      this.buttons = input.buttons;
    }
  }
}
```

Now everything works fine with this, but what i want to do right now is to pass a function to my service in order for it to consume it. Something like this but i don't know how :

```
{
  function: (modalComponent) => {
    modalComponent.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try removing `async` from the callback definition and handle the click event with: `(click)="act.callback(this)"`.

Comment: it's not working :/

Comment: Can you post the problem in stackblitz so we can solve it better? Because you can pass a `function` as a `callback parameter` without problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your callback is expecting to take in a `modalComponent` as a parameter, but your html is doing nothing of the sort at just `(click)="act.callback"`.

In your current code, you're constructing a method that looks, essentially, like this:

```
var myCallback = function(modalComponent) {
  modalComponent.close();
}
// ...
var someObj = {
  name: "Close",
  callback: myCallback
}
```

And so calling it, something would eventually need to do:

```
// ...
var modalComp = getComponent(); // however it gets hold of a modalComponent
someObj.callback(modalComp);
```

The method needs to be given a modalComponent to work on, but when calling it, you are not giving it one - in your current code.

So, either your current calling of the callback needs to give the modal you want to close as the input (akin to the comment by @ConnorsFan, assuming `this` is the relevant reference to the modal), or you change your method to already know about the modal.

```
var myModal = ...;
var myObj = {
  name: "Close",
  callback: () => { myModal.close(); }
}
```

Now usage just looks like this, as there is no input params:

```
myObj.callback();
```

Anonymous functions are useful for cheekily making use of resources that don't really exist in the caller's scope.

Comment: but when i do so, i get an error that ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: modalComponent.close is not a function

Comment: Does your modal component expose a public `close()` method? How are you gaining that reference to the modalComponent?

Answer (score 4):

Just like your buttons, you can pass your methods/callbacks to your service and then call them from within the service, e.g.

```
openConfirmModal() {
  this.service.openmodal({
    buttons: [ {name: 'Close'} ],
    methods: {
      onClose: () => {/** your function body goes here */},
      onSubmit: () => {/** your function body goes here*/}
      .
      .
      .
    }
  });
}
```

And then in your service, you can call them whenever you like.

Check this also
[click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638990/are-strongly-typed-functions-as-parameters-possible-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple **javascript/typescript** to solve this, using just a `callback` method.

Your `service function` would be something like this:

```
serviceFunction(callback?) {
  const cb = callback || (() => { });
  // do your services thing
  return cb();
}
```

So when you call it you just call the `serviceFunction` with the `callback function` you want to use.

Considering that you have a `this.close()` method in your `component`, the call 
 would look like:

```
myService.serviceFunction(this.close);
```