# can the type specified after the colons in typescript be a function?

Tags: typescript

I have encountered this export declaration in TypeScript inside a module.d.ts:

```js
export declare const extend: (objects: object) => void
```

is "const extend" type an object and why does it return void instead of the type specified ?

Comment: What do you mean "instead of the type specified"? The return type specified is `void`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are strongly-typed functions as parameters possible in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638990/are-strongly-typed-functions-as-parameters-possible-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

`export declare const extend` means that:

constant `extend` has been declared and it has a type of function : `(objects: object) => void`.

Hence, `extend` is a function.

Above code is equal (except `declared` keyword) to:

```js
export const extend=(objects: object) => { 
   /* function implementation which returns nothing */ 
}
```

Comment: ah thanks I was confused because I thought that it would be something like:   

export declare const extend: funtion;
extend = function():void{
/*function implmentaiton*/
}

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but this syntax: `const extend: funtion; extend = function():void{ /*function implmentaiton*/ }` is invalid.

Comment: it is just that I found this in react-three-fiber package and it used apparently to export modules like: 

module sth:
````
classs sth {
/* class body*/
}
extend ({sth});
````
should not the function in extend return the passed object ?
anyway never mind I guess I have to learn typescript extensivly. thank you

Comment: @AbdulsalamAlmahdi I recommend you to start from TS handbook https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html

Comment: `function` is the keyword to define the function as JS code. `() => T` is the syntax to declare the function **type** :)