# How can I make a function parameter respect an object type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
const someCollection = {};

/**
 * @param id
 * @param callback The callback will be given an object with keys `a1` (of type "string") and `a2` (of type "number").
 */
const addSomething = (id, callback) => {
  someCollection[id] = { callback };
};

const getSomething = (id) => {
  return someCollection[id];
};

addSomething("someId", ({ arg1, arg2 }) => {
  console.log(arg1, arg2);
});

const something = getSomething("someId");

something.callback({ arg1: "hey", arg2: 2 });
```

If you take a look at `addSomething`'s comment about the `callback` param, it says that it would like to receive a callback with two parameters, in the shape of: `arg1: string, arg2: number`, together with the `id`, this forms an item in our collection. To note that we'll put the callback under the `callback` index inside our collection. Let's go ahead and `addSomething` and you can tell it all works once we retrieve it and print it all. Our output should be `hey, 2`. Well, let's write this in TS:

```
const someCollection: { [index: string]: any } = {};

type CallbackType = {
  new(
  a1: string,
  a2: number
  ): void
};

function addSomething(id: string, callback: CallbackType): void {
  console.log( `${type.a1} + ${type.a2}`);
}


addSomething('someId', ({a1: 'hey', a2: 2 }))
```

Well, it doesn't work. I can tell the code is wrong, I just don't know how to fix it. The first cue is that TS probably doesn't know how to handle "named arguments" and when I `addSomething`, I'm really just passing a function with an object as its **one, single parameter**. The second cue is that `callback` is just...well, uh...not sure? It surely isn't a function.

In short, I'd like for anyone that passes a callback to `addSomething` to respect the rules of the `CallbackType` type and pass named arguments, `arg1` and `arg2` respectively, with the correct types.

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: Why does your `CallbackType` have a `new` in its call signature? And you are trying to pass the object `{a1: 'hey', a2: 2}` as an argument; this object is blatantly not a callback function.

Comment: Are you saying the first code is _correct_, and you're trying to write types for it? Then the comment is wrong, or at least misleading - the callback will be given a single argument that's an object _containing_ arg1 and arg2. Could you expand on _"doesn't work"_? Not only does the type (TypeScript) not seems right, the actual _call_ (JavaScript) doesn't make sense given the previous snippet. It's unclear what specific problem you're trying to solve, but you're not going to be able to write the correct types if you can't follow the code to start with.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I fixed the comment, you're right, it was misleading. It's passing an object with these keys, that is to say, `addSomething`'s second parameter is a callback, which in turn has an object with these keys as its parameter. Not sure what to say about "what doesn't work", it just...doesn't? If I were to tldr my question (and, trust me, I've searched plenty) it'd be: how can I make I (1) take a function as a parameter and (2) how can I make sure that function's arguments match a certain type?

Comment: @kaya3 Correct. I just wanted to showcase what I've been trying to do.

Comment: _"it just...doesn't?"_ - you tell us. How do _you know_ it doesn't work? Errors? At runtime? Compilation time? What are they? Unexpected outputs? For what inputs? Please read [ask] and give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's a question of "how do I even write this stuff, given my requirements?". I thought it was obvious that the code I provided isn't correct from the get-go, just the result of my many attempts to make it work. The editor's telling me that there are all kinds of stuff, so, I know that what I wrote is not even proper syntax. **I can't even write syntax to actually get an error out of it or something.** I also looked at the docs, reading about Object Types and functions and so on, yet, I can't find a single example that deals with my use-case.

Comment: Your first example shows you exactly how to write that stuff; it's _written_. What are you actually trying to achieve? Is it to add types to the first example? If so, why do you also change the _implementation_? What _are_ the things the editor is telling you? What does running `tsc` tell you?

Comment: Hey guys I explained below how to add types in the implementation from @James .

Comment: A better starting point might be to put your working JavaScript into e.g. [a playground](https://tsplay.dev/wj43lm) and see what the compiler says about it. But making random guesses (e.g. you never call `new callback(...)`, why add a construct signature?) in the absence of any feedback isn't going to get you anywhere. Or research your more specific questions, _"how can I make I (1) take a function as a parameter and (2) how can I make sure that function's arguments match a certain type?"_ -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/14638990/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know where you're coming from. This is not a case of not doing research and not having spent hours on the issue. I genuinely have no idea how to write the thing and the only thing I have left is bruteforcing syntax. I (think) know what TS is asking of me, I just don't know how to write it. It's genuinely *just that*.

Comment: Then you need a tutorial, SO isn't a code-writing service. And where you've done research, it's helpful to summarise it in the question (this is also in the linked guidance).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
interface Something {
    callback: SomethingCallback
}

type SomethingCallback = (obj: {arg1: string, arg2: number}) => void;

const someCollection: { [id: string]: Something } = {};

const addSomething = (id: string, callback: SomethingCallback) => {
  someCollection[id] = { callback };
};

const getSomething = (id: string) => {
  return someCollection[id];
};

addSomething("someId", ({ arg1, arg2 }) => {
  console.log(arg1, arg2);
});

const something = getSomething("someId");

something.callback({ arg1: "hey", arg2: 2 });
```

### An explanation

At first, we declare the types we need. An interface `Something` that will be stored in the collection. This is an object that contains a key `callback` and a value of type `SomethingCallback`.

```
interface Something {
  callback: SomethingCallback
}
```

The type `SomethingCallback` represents a function that takes one parameter. The parameter must contain 2 keys `arg1` of type `string`, and `arg2` of type `number`:

```
type SomethingCallback = (obj: {arg1: string, arg2: number}) => void;
```

Here is how to declare the type of `someCollection`. It is an object used as a dictionary. In TS this pattern is called an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures):

```
const someCollection: { [id: string]: Something } = {};
```

Then, all you have to do is to use the types as annotations in `addSomething` and `getSomething` parameters.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you. I tried a bit more on my own, but to no avail. Your answer works, I understand what's happening. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I believe I know why your answer got down-voted. While it works, this is not "good" TS code as `SomethingCallback`'s parameters will not be seen by whoever's using `addSomething`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70420028/how-come-typescript-cant-see-the-fields-of-a-type-in-a-function-parameter