# How come TypeScript can't see the fields of a type in a function parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have a `packages` object, to which I add items of the `Package` type (
[Plain JS "what I'm trying to achieve"](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-breeze-i1kg5?file=/src/index.js) also [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNZQLxQBQD2yAVgFxQDeAUFFAM4ECuATmhOXcMwJYB2A5gBoaUUJDocuffgG0AusNoBbCMDgB%20chQC%20VbQEocAPigA3AtwAmAbipU%20wCMwBm6aAAV0GOP2jVaaIgoXuTwSKiYtrpUaAS8nFBgXj4QEpRQMkmYKQCSlpI8AnLkntm%20UNo4lNq2MXEJcJaWpd7luHgiWa0QeQXSilCB4SGwQREYVIbYJv6Jyb50mfM9lnJVFINjXhVR1kA)), as such:

```
type Callback = (obj: {
  source: string,
  types: string[],
  meta?: {}
}) => void;

interface Package {
  callback: Callback;
}

const packages: { [packageId: string]: Package } = {};

const addPackage = (
  packageId: string,
  callback: Callback
) => {
  packages[packageId] = { callback };
};
```

If I were to start typing `addPackage('somePackage'`, TS will tell me that `packageId` is of type `string`, but all it can tell me about `callback` is that it's of type `Callback`:

[image]

While it does show what `callback`'s fields are if I type it **as a function**:

[image]

I won't get this information unless I know that `callback` needs to be a function which has an object with these keys as its argument.

How can I let someone that's using `addPackage` know that `callback` is a function with the fields of `Callback`?

The shape of my object (in plain JS) should end up looking like this:

```js
{
  123: {
    callback: () => {
      //Whatever was added as a callback from `addPackage`.
      //Naturally, we are also given access to the parameters 'source' and 'types' here.
    }

  }
}
```

---

As a side-note, TS borks even further when I start typing `callbacks`'s properties. It doesn't see them anymore, so, there's no highlighting:

[image]

*I'm open to heavy criticism, as I'm learning TS. If you have a better idea on how to write this, I'm all ears and I appreciate it a lot.*

Comment: If you don't want the callback type to appear as a name instead of the expanded type definition, then you don't have to give it a name in the first place - the fact that you gave it a name suggests it is OK to refer to it by name. What I mean is that you can write `callback: (obj: {source: string, types: string[], meta?: {}}) => void` instead of `callback: Callback`, and then that's what will appear in the hover text. But it seems undesirable to do this, because `(obj: {source: string, types: string[], meta?: {}}) => void` is much less readable than `Callback`.

Comment: TS (language service) could recursively resolve all types down to primitives, but that would lose all abstraction and lead to gigantic signatures in many cases. As with most things, this is a tradeoff. Practically speaking "callback" should make it clear to most users that a function is expected.

Comment: @kaya3 That actually makes sense, however, I don't know how else to write this in order for it to work. You're right. I started with the wrong intent.

Comment: If you are worried that people won't know from the name `Callback` that a function is expected, I think it would make more sense to just write a doc comment `/** ... */` explaining what the function `addPackage` is and how it should be called.

Comment: @IngoBürk The thing here is that I don't believe this code is even "good". I'm new to TS, but not new to strongly-typed systems, but two-level deep lookups should not be a problem? I think?

Comment: As for your side-note, what you are writing there with `source: 'none'` does not make sense in context because you are expected to write a function there, not an object with properties - so it would not make sense for Typescript to give you hints about how to write an object there.

Comment: @JanosVinceller I'll assume your solution works, but isn't that contrived? I have a feeling that this shouldn't be something I have to fight for. I guess my question is really about HOW TO write the functionality I desire, so, I already started with the wrong template.

Comment: Okay, now I understand your intention. I think if using Callback as a method call parameter, you could put variables or properties there, that are of type Callback, so no reason to explain that further. If you're at constructing a new Callback it helps you to build up that structure and therefore the IDE tells you the properties of Callback. That would make sense for me.

Comment: @JanosVinceller Yes. As of now, if I were to do `addPackage('123', (callback => ({ source: 'none', types: ['typeA', 'typeb']})));`, I couldn't even write something for the `callbacks`'s body at all. It's an empty function.

Comment: @JanosVinceller Sorry if this is a miscommunication on my end, but `callback` is a function. The parameters are there for someone to know what they need to pass in. The object would look as follows: `{ 123: { callback: ()`. You could then call it with `packages['123'].callback({ source: 'none', types: ['typeA']})`. So, if my callback was `console.log(source, types[0]`, it would spit out `'none', 'typeA`.

Comment: Oh no, sorry again, it's my fault. Now I really see the problem. Before you type in those (), the IDE shows only the type Callback, but not that it is a function, right?

Comment: Okay, the thing is the following: `Callback` IS itself not a `function`, but "contains" a function. But: the `addPackage` method wants a parameter of type `Callback`. That's okay and this is what your IDE shows you. Now as you write those parenthesis, your IDE shows you the content of the type Callback. And at the end of that text you'll see the `:void` which tells you it is a method you have to put in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240284/discussion-between-janos-vinceller-and-james).

Comment: "As a side-note, TS borks even further when I start typing callbacks's properties." - that's because this half-written code doesn't have a `=>` yet so it could very well be an attempt to write an object literal instead of an arrow function.

Comment: @CherryDT Correct. The TS docs are sparse (not that it's a bad thing) on functions and I can't seem to find any tutorials by keyword. This could be because I'm new, so, not sure how to piece information together.

Comment: @CherryDT For reference, this is the plain-JS of what I'm trying to achieve: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-breeze-i1kg5?file=/src/index.js

Comment: _"As a side-note, TS borks even further when I start typing callbacks's properties"_ Add the arrow first, then TS will recognize you write a function and it will helps with auto-completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-7znmjv

Inlined here:

```
type Callback = (callbackParams: {
  source: string;
  types: string[];
  meta?: {};
}) => void;

const packages = {};

const addPackage = (id: string, callback: Callback) => {
  packages[id] = callback;
};

addPackage('123', (params: { source: string; types: string[]; meta?: {} }) => {
  console.log(params.source);
});

packages['123']({ source: 'hey', types: [] });
```

Comment: Or even more easier to understand: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zv4lxt

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the answer since it does what it's supposed to, but the problems with TS still persist, e.g, when I `addPackage(...`, I'm not told exactly what `callbacks`'s fields are, but as it was explained to me, this is expected behavior.