# Function type return value less strict then required (allows wider values)

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling to understand type checking in the context of a functions return value.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyyARnFAFzIDOYUoA5gQL4EED0byAvD73-wMFDB7TgHUAFhBBpMyYFWQATYFAgIwAGwCeyOFSrB6ICEtb4OyAArQY6sMHQgAhAQROayGJkoYsXHBIySgByUigQ5BZ8UWQAWQVDEHpkAAcodFToMF0AgCE4M3x3EE8QdHDfOQDsKIIiSysMrKgc5DCySIVkAFtEhnkZHKz27CZI4gBXMGQ1AEdJ1VNB5GGUEL8QgDoACgAmAHYAFgBGAEpzSwBRAA9aODTm7NzkAqKSz28K4Nl-QMr2uEQgAaZAQO5QOCUE5RZD1ZCWAAq2hGIVqAJodGSAG4wRCocgQJMesRoLjxvJFOUZvpDMY4MRNCgwFg1u1Nls4YQEZwAPLEABW9mQmmAkEhml6cF0Th01CyCGAMF0AGtygB3GTpTLZYAQKiguAgJTtcH3SJKdD6wnoGbghQzUCrFHrDn7ADMez2FxiFk4wgDgaDXFikmkv0pqykswgYEmUBkADc4JpJih0DA9F5JiANI4QJdODZYPZ865ih4Zl9UDmEJQdmduAA+CMBBvN5A7dE-DoRKI+2IJAwDbUtNr5QpuSs28I13P1xtcFt+bidxctrv9+GNJ6tXS9rqKPrD5IrNloilTGbzRZqE1O89uw6nAd+5C3e6PHV71dvKelKtMFnWsFw7Fc23XTtuwoQFOlBM1IWhLduUsABlQodFBalkAQOBJnoCQZmIXQ1ioBA6FSMBC3ffEvzHF4-wrACvEwasQLXMDqjXKp-A3aDQiBeD8SQpgfQaThkVRfjqFoBhcQQgkiRJMkokPG0aWHelGWZVkXXZTBti5cTkH5IUNBFMVoBTKUZRAOUqAVJVVQ1LVdwcfVDWNU18QtK0qVtPEHTPPSNgM3Y9k9b1qODGLYpDN8ADVgAeABxaRoGAXDkHVMUJBwlNNFIBAVXMGBawcJwvyQAwAB5ESbHZcM0QrEBVUCl2QREzkoREcHhNQ4wTfLmqKlUG2YaihySFJR2eUEr2Qeh0roBB1PldQlT1E0dioLBQDsKA7y8DIemGlripjQaQB9bVqqoHZ2w6zdRNfa5aNmvd5umRblsytaHI2mAts7XbBgOo6YBOs7Rsu+NroIW79Xux6+KCGCDyE+4RLOV7OCmkc3O0L6ZiWkwVvWxUgdMUEBrh50RmTUUlDgCqZDgVJUlFUwEYyO6ar8BqUag-sxJ5axCdgvtumPabgqky9vpvJZ7yGEKn2Oc5qI-SE6Lmn6yb+gHKa24mbTBQ70CgHn0D5gWHsgzcAQxvEseQGEXu3Th0KUTC1tw-DCJIEiXTIiiqN9N7Pw+nJQVJjLVqNzbqeh1q8U5zKxTlJQICBkxFFpoa1ngi2oFmOAFG5-BEdqu2Gx4jtHZ7QSXcQt2Rc9zqQukzE5JbxTiVJKByTU7DaSMEAGSZVZdNRDkjLF0zhVFcVrJ6aVkFlXRE+VZA1XQTVddaPUDT0LyQgU3zrWw+1PAfNWwo9L0fSAA)

Let's look at something that we know to be valid:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: string
}

const foo: Foo = { bar: 'bar' }
  // Good!
```

Then experiment with expected exceptions:

```
// Missing property = Bad
const nobar: Foo = { }
  // Property 'bar' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Foo'.(2741)

// Extra property = Bad
const foobar: Foo = { bar: 'bar', extra: 1 } 
  // Type '{ bar: string; extra: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Foo'. 
  // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'extra' does not exist in type 'Foo'.(2322)
```

And then introduce Foo as the return type of a function:

```
// Perfection!
const fooFunc: () => Foo = () => ({ bar: 'bar' })

// Missing property = Bad
const nobarFunc: () => Foo = () => ({ })
  // Property 'bar' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Foo'.(2741)

// Extra property = Bad
const foobarFunc: () => Foo = () => ({ bar: 'bar', extra: 1 })
  // Sadly, not caught by typescript
```

In my use case, the function is a callback, and I want the return type to be validated in the function (that the return value is compatible with Foo).

If I add an explicit return type to the arrow function definition, I get the expected validation (markers to show what I've added):

```
// Extra property = Bad
const foofooFunc: () => Foo = ()/*>>*/: Foo/*<<*/ => ({ bar: 'bar', extra: 1 })
  // Type '{ bar: string; extra: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Foo'. 
  // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'extra' does not exist in type 'Foo'.(2322)
```

I originally ran into this in the context of a generic function that takes a call back that should be typed on the return value.

```
function process<T>(callback: () => T): T {
  return callback()
}

// Missing property, but generic not specified (so inferred from callback return)
process(() => ({ }))

// Extra property, but generic not specified (so inferred from callback return)
process(() => ({ bar: 'bar', extra: 1 }))

// Missing property, but generic specified, return type validation applied
process<Foo>(() => ({ }))
  // Property 'bar' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Foo'.(2741)

// Extra property, generic specified, but no error
process<Foo>(() => ({ bar: 'bar', extra: 1 }))
  // Sadly, not caught by typescript

// Extra property, generic specified, callback explicitly defines return type, error raised
process<Foo>((): Foo => ({ bar: 'bar', extra: 1 }))
  // Type '{ bar: string; extra: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Foo'. 
  // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'extra' does not exist in type 'Foo'.(2322)
```

It seems that in the case of a return value type, the type is acceptible if its at least the same shape, as opposed to exactly the same shape in the case of direct assignment.

I appreciate that an interface is essentially a subset of a wider type, but there seems to be a difference in how this is applied (sometimes its strict equality, other times a narrowing).

I also understand that this is likely the intended behaviour, but I am a bit surprised that the specified type on the generic doesn't get applied to the callback, its as if the type is coerced because its 'at least the same shape' instead of equal.  That might be because there are genuinely valid cases where a return type is narrowed.

Obviously my application is more complex than this, and whilst typing the callback works, its easy to forget and then there is the risk of no type checking being applied at all (both the generic type and the callback return must be specified).  What's more, the extra verbosity turns it into word salad and obfuscates the rest of the intention.

It's not possible to specify an `extends` on the generic as its intended to be, well, generic!  ie, there is no based type beyond `object`.  Also, the callback does have input parameters, but these are also generic, no meaningful base type.

There is a related but somewhat misnamed question ([Are strongly-typed functions as parameters possible in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638990/are-strongly-typed-functions-as-parameters-possible-in-typescript)) which is only really dealing with how to type a function aside from `function`.

**Update 1:**

@Justus reply lead me to:

```
type Strictly<T> = T & { [key in any]: never }
```

This solves the dilemma, but gives a new one, which is that in my application the return type can be `T | null`, and `null` is being merged in the Strictly, so somehow I need to make this conditional.  More later when I have time.

**Update 2:**

Probably best to make a clear example of what I want.  In essence, the `process` function takes a callback which is passed arbitrary input, and the callback returns whether the input matches the type specified to the generic call.

NB: This is much simplified but shows the issue with return type being inexact (wider) than the specified type. In reality, the callback is setup and utilised later in the application when data is being processed.

```
// One of many types

interface Foo { 
  bar: string
}

// A function that validates arbitrary input and returns either a known type or null (if the input is unknown)

function process<T>(callback: (input: any) => T | null): T | null {
  return callback('some arbitrary data')
}

// Example usage, generic specifies the desired return type of callback

// This works, its an exact match for Foo
process<Foo>(input => ({ bar: 'bar' }))

// This is a type error, missing property 'bar'
process<Foo>(input => ({ }))

// This is accepted, but has an extra parameter, ideally should be a type error
process<Foo>(input => ({ bar: 'bar', extra: 1 }))

// This works, indicates input does not match a known type
process<Foo>(input => (null))
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHkDsFNQewGagLYENIE9QBcMAdoBnAWACgyBLSbaAJwVQGNYAxOOUAb1DNFACNUtAFyhC2WlQDmZAL5kyIUAEFQCAK6RG2CnEg4AFqmygAbqgA2FACbGioIfwoShWKnnUn010LWjZ1WkhCUGhnAzoHUABrSDgAd31cAnhaUEh1CwtQAAoKJGwI0HdPYpDNWITIAEoFUg0tHT1QPFo4ZkJCAB4AFQA+HMZLC0FGaNE8yA9sUXQMatAAXj7QHtAAH3TMi2rRNc2MrK5eX39A-SGs0eicgHJCOGRYR2daV1BbbFRb2tJ5clISgAogAPVDIPAWWDqQioKTQAA0oHhMEkjDEBEY+Qo9kKsGsRAofh8fgCQRw+FgiFAlxGTGidSUPQMFBC8TgtGihCRzhC6FCYO0KGMjAMag5oDYcDIrXaRG6UoGJRMy1y3EEIlAtw1t1Asmqv0UYGZrLKUWSsDobVoSOQrMI0habQItFwWp1MraHQV7CVU1Kqpy3H1hsBxpZIVNTGYeBo1iR-FKRj5+mgIJcLSE4P8dB5BOGWEIBjgmR8-GeFJSVo5nrlnS6ism0yWKyDAiEom1QluSLTLlEAEY9QbGeHTezOdzipBrBQhjRI-6TNY4PY4iY0NhRVFKolK9Ba96G76mwHW4cdtUgA)

What I want to ensure is that when the callback is being written the compiler shows when the return type varies from the expectation.  This can be solved by putting the return type on the arrow function instead of as the generic parameter, thus:

```
process((input: any): Foo => {
  // ...

  // extra parameter, shown as type error
  return { bar: 'bar': extra: 1 }
})
```

I feel this is:

a) verbose, because it requires the function to be fully typed when it could be inferred by the generic

b) flakey, because if the arrow is untyped, it will allow a wider return type than expected

This is what I'm finding confusing - there is a different in interpretation depending on whether the compiler is inferring the return type than from when its explicit.

I can't find a way of specifying through conditional generics that the return type should have a specific shape.  I sort of think that the `Omit<>` utility type would help, but can't find a form that works, such that `Exact<A, B>` where `A` is specified and `B` is inferred from the callback return type, would ensure that anything remaining in B after omitting A would evalute to `never`.

Comment: Update 1 doesn't work, it also prevents known properties, something I wasn't checking for in my tests.  The null issue doesn't appear to be a problem after all.

Comment: There is a long discussion on the Typescript Issues here on 'exact' types : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936

Answer (score 0):

#### IMPORTANT: This does not work, see Update 3

I think as you've already mentioned that that is expected behaviour. You probably want to be able to assign methods that don't quite match but overlap as your callback, like for example:

```
function withCallbackA(cb: () => {key: string, key2: string}): unknown {
   // do sth.
}

function withCallbackB(cb: () => {key: string}): unknown {
   // do sth.
}

function callback(): {key: string, key2: string} {
   // do sth.
}

withCallbackA(callback)
withCallbackB(callback)
```

If you don't want that behaviour you could use something along the lines of

```js
function withCallbackC(cb: () => {key1: string} & Record<string|number,never>): unknown {
   // do sth.
}

withCallbackC(callback) // will give something along the lines of "Argument of type '() => { key1: string; key2: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => {key1: string} & Record<string | number, never>'."
```

and explicitly type other keys as never or non-existent.

In case of the above example you could just use a type like `{key1: string, [key in string| number]: never}` instead, but as that would not work with your interface I'd reccoment to just stick to the `... & Record<string|number, never>`

=======

#### @ Update 1

I think I kinda get it what you mean but at the same time I kinda don't. is your function declaration something along the lines of

```js
function test<T extends Record<string | number, unknown>>(cb: () => T | null> {...}
```

or is it more like

```
function test<T extends Record<string | number, unknown> | null>(cb: () => T> {...}
```

?

if the second case is your problem you could just use something like

```js
type Strictly<T extends Record<string | number, unknown> | null> = T extends null? null: T & Record<string | number, never>
```

## @ Update 3

I am sorry, but I realized that what I said eariler doesn't work as I had expected, at least for me. I think what you describe is currently simply not possible in Typescript. See the issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936 as commented by Dave on his question. Alternatively you could wait for https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16607 and write a plugin for that yourself.

What I've found is that you can use something like

```js
type TestStrictMatch<T extends Record<any,any>, TestObj, TypeMatch, TypeNotMatch> = TestObj extends T? T extends TestObj? TypeMatch: TypeNotMatch: TypeNotMatch
```

as a "test" if the type does strictly match and define a type based on if it does. I don't think that will help you though.

Sorry I could not be of any help :/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Firstly, I inadvertantly edited your reply instead of my original question.  I've reverted it, but it needs approval.  I've added the update to the end of my question.

Comment: Thanks again, the suggested doesn't seem to compile when used (`Strictly<T>` complains about T).  I've added an update #2

Comment: Thanks again, I don't think `TestStrictMatch` is really much different than `never` for a non-match.  I agree, the issue of exact matches in Typescript still seems to be an outstanding issue and I can accept that I need to live with the limitations as they stand.  Bravo for stepping through it with me.